# Probability of a quantum particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

Now recently I have started quantum mechanics and I understood the wavefunction but I don't understand why $|Ψ|^2$ gives the probability density of a quantum particle. Is there a reason or perhaps maths behind it?

Comment: $|\Psi(x)|^2 dx$ can be seen as a probability measure in the mathematical sense

Comment: I have never heard a satisfying argument about such a deep question. Hence, the only advice I am able to provide is a comment of my former professor: "The only way to learn quantum mechanics is to repeat the math over and over. You stop when  you have forgotten your initial questions."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $|\Psi|^2$ the probability density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107743/)

Answer (score 0):

Related [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107743/why-is-psi2-the-probability-density?rq=1), but I'm sure there are many answers out there, so I won't say much.

I think the reason is basically that it makes sense and it works. Formally, I think it is generally considered as a postulate which makes sense only because experiments agree with it.